# DOMの読み方とアクセントの位置

Tags: javascript

DOMの読み方とアクセントの位置について。
皆さんどのように呼んでいますか？日本で、広く浸透しているものがあれば教えてください。

正解は無いのかなとも思いますが、円滑なコミュニケーションを取るために知っておきたいと思った次第です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

意見が分かれそうな気もしますが、私は[このように](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=ja&q=dom)発声しています。

Comment: 音声データまでつけていただき、ありがとうございます。とても参考になりました。確かに、この手の単語は、後ろにアクセントを置かれる方が多い印象があります。

Answer (score 1):

何を参考にしたわけでもありませんが、勝手に「ドム」で「ド」にアクセントをおいて発音しています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。今までなんとなく「ドム」と呼んでいましたが、masmさんもtutinocoさんも同じように読まれていて安心しました。